# Hibernate composite keys with abstract class

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to have a Employee table with composit primary key (personID,departmentName) keeping

the Person's class @id annotation , also keeping as it is a abstract class.

```
public abstract class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;


    // Getter and Setter methods, 
}



@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
public class Employee extends Person {

    @Column(name="joining_date")
    private Date joiningDate;

    @Column(name="department_name")
    private String departmentName;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String firstname, String lastname, String departmentName, Date joiningDate) {

        super(firstname, lastname);

        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

    // Getter and Setter methods, 
}
```